# Adding text using SED

Tags: linux, unix, sed

i am working with a task right now, manipulating text in Unix, but i have no idea how i will do it. I am planning to use sed. this is wat i am trying to do.

I have this text.

```
BS111

xxxxx
yyyyy
zzzzz

BS112

xxxxx
yyyyy
zzzzz

BS113

xxxxx
yyyyy
zzzzz

so on.. with this kind of format
```

and i want it to be like:

```
BS111 xxxxx
BS111 yyyyy
BS111 zzzzz



BS112 xxxxx
BS112 yyyyy
BS112 zzzzz



BS113 xxxxx
BS113 yyyyy
BS113 zzzzz

so on.. with this kind of format
```

the BS* and its data occurs almost hundred times. so i think the best way to do it is to use a script. thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `awk`

`awk '/^BS/{i=$0; next;} {if(length($0)) printf("%s ",i); print $0}' <filename>`

Update:

'/^BS/{i=$0; next;} {if(length($0)) printf("%s ",i); print $0}' remember, in awk, `{...}` denotes a set of action. `/pattern/{...}` means if a pattern is found, do `{...}` actions.
`/^BS[0-9]/` will search for pattern in each line. If the pattern is found, `i` (variable in awk) will be updated with the pattern ($0 is complete line) and `next` will immidiately move to next line.So next set of action in `{if(...}` will be skipped if a pattern is found. So `i` will always contain the last pattern value and if a line is containing pattern, except updating i, next set of action will not take place for the line.

Next set of action is, `if(length($0))` if, the line contains text, `printf("%s ",i); print the last found pattern, And then`print $0`prints the original line. So for an empty line, only an empty line is printed, if some text is there, first the`i`or`last found pattern` is printed, then the original line is printed. Btw, sputnick's solution is also doing the same thing, only in a more compact form. So you can dissect that one also for fun. Hope i am clear, please feel free to ask anything you need to know

Comment: welcome  :) if you are interested, it can be done in sed. Also it can be done in simple bash, without any external tools, but `awk` is cleaner than others. `perl` also gives a nice solution.

Comment: it doesn't matter that it CAN be done in sed or bash or whatever. You should never use bash for text manipulation. sed is the right tool for simple substitutions on a single line (which this is not). awk is the right tool for all other text manipulation. perl is the tool for other problems if you don't want to use a combination of bash+awk+etc.

Comment: I agree with all the points, but still i believe stop trying means stop learning :) who knows, may be i'll learn something new while doing in bash, which will help me later in something else

Comment: @abasu thank you again. I replaced ../^BS/.. with ../^BS[0-9]+/.. to make the code choose only BS+Number format. If you have time and you dont have anything to do right now i am hoping you discuss to me how every part of this code works. thank you again :)

Comment: thanks @abasu! I really appreciate it. you explained that in a very comprehensive way. you should consider teaching in a university.

Comment: ha ha :) nice suggestion :D .. thnx

Answer (score 3):

With awk :

```
awk '/^BS/{v=$0;next} {print (/^$/) ? $0 : v, $0}' file.txt

BS111 xxxxx
BS111 yyyyy
BS111 zzzzz


BS112 xxxxx
BS112 yyyyy
BS112 zzzzz


BS113 xxxxx
BS113 yyyyy
BS113 zzzzz
```

Comment: More & more concise now with a _ternary operator_

Comment: thank you again for answering :) this almost work for me. but there have some problems. there are actually instances that the data under BS* have the same format as it is like bscja. so there are tendencies that code works as it should not be. is there a way to only choose BS112 (BS and number) and not BSCJA (BS and string)?

Comment: just ignore my comment above. I just edited the code. and it now works! thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/^BS/{h;d};/./!b;G;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2 \1/' file
```

Comment: thank you for answering. I just wanna know what '/^BS/{h;d};/.... means? what i am trying to do is to get only texts with BS+number format. there is intances that under BS112, exists data such as BSCHR, BSWER etc. so the output is not what it is supposed to be

Comment: @jonas for lines beginning with BS+number format just make the pattern more specific i.e. change `/^BS/` to `/^BS[0-9]+/`

Answer (score 1):

In [sed](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) you can do:

```
sed -n -r '/^BS[0-9]{3}/{h;d};/./G;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2 \1/p' test.txt
```

`-n` means sed wont output anything unless told to by the `p` command.
`-r` means using extended regular expressions.

`/^BS[0-9]{3}/{h;d}` matches a line starting with BS and three numbers, the `h` command puts the pattern into the holding buffer (copies it for later insertion). The `d` command deletes the matched line.

`/./G` matches any line. The `G` command appends the content of the holding buffer (in this case BSxxx). `s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2 \1/p` matches the current and the next line, switches them and removes the newline. And finally the `p` command prints the resulting line

Comment: thank you for your very comprehensive reply. i will try this also. I will tell you if it works :)